# Temporary Table in if statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
IF @someVariable = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    INTO #TempTable
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Category="Something"
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    INTO #TempTable
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Category="SomethingElse"
END
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Comes up with "There is already an object named '#TempTable' in the database. Is there a way around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Insert Into Temp Table in both If and Else Blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155996/sql-insert-into-temp-table-in-both-if-and-else-blocks)

Comment: What is the reason you want to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
IF @someVariable = 0
BEGIN
   SELECT * 
   INTO #TempTable1
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE Category="Something"
   DROP TABLE #TempTable1
 END
ELSE
 BEGIN
   SELECT * 
   INTO #TempTable2
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE Category="SomethingElse"
   DROP TABLE #TempTable2
END
```

This will work, but depending on what else you may need the code to do, might not be the best solution; but in your example code it solves the problem.

Alternatively:

```
SELECT * into #TempTable from MyTable where (1=0)

IF @someVariable = 0
   INSERT INTO #TempTable SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Category="Something"
ELSE
   INSERT INTO #TempTable SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Category="OtherSomething"

DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Answer (score 2):

Would a table variable fit your needs... I prefer these because of these scoping issues.

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (
    -- Your definition
)

IF @someVariable = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @TempTable (...)
    SELECT ...
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Category="Something"
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @TempTable (...)
    SELECT ...
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Category="SomethingElse"
END
```

Or are you trying to prevent having to explicitly define the columns?  Can you refactor to determine the condition beforehand:

```
DECLARE @Category varchar(100)
IF @someVariable = 0
BEGIN
    SET @Category = "Something"
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Category = "SomethingElse"
END

SELECT * 
INTO #TempTable
FROM MyTable
WHERE Category = @Category

DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be a table variable, though. The same approach would work with a temporary table as well.

Comment: So what are you trying to do... just get around explicitly declaring the column definitions?

Comment: Did you mean to address that question at the OP? Anyway, you probably forgot to remove `INTO @TempTable` after `SELECT ...` (in both queries).